# How to convert "Friday-2015-August-07" to "2015-08-07"

Tags: java, android

Well, its weird i have tried formatting the string "Friday-2015-August-07" to  "2015-08-07" as string but failed.

Can anyone please help me to convert them? input, output both should be in String.

So, it should be:

```
from:: String str_input = "Friday-2015-August-07";
to::  String str_output = "2015-08-07";
```

or even from the below input, as i have splited the str_input and made it like below:

```
from:: String str_input = "2015-August-07";
```

But the first one which is **"Friday-2015-August-07"** is preferable for input.

Comment: hope you would have googled first convert https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%E2%80%9CFriday-2015-August-07%E2%80%9D++to+yyyy-MM-dd+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=be_CVd65NNWKuASOq6eYCg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try {

        String str_input = "Friday-2015-August-07";

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE-yyyy-MMMM-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat formatTarget = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String str_output=formatTarget.format(format.parse(str_input));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man!! Helped me a lot!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take str_input in pattern `"Friday-2015-August-07"`,  You can try:

```
String datas[] = str_input.split("-");
String str_output = datas[1] + monthStr2Num(datas[2]) + datas[3];
```